# List of Strongly typed objects to list of dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic

OK. I'm trying to take a `List<Product>` and pass it into a method that takes a generic `List<object>` and loops over them to create a `List<dynamic>` via reflection. This method needs to be able to handle lists of other objects (ie: Item, Customer, Package, etc).

The idea is then so that I'll have a generic list of dynamic that I could send via JSON across the wire.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest approach is to just use LINQ to build a new list. Given that you're using .NET 4, you've got covariance available to you, so you can use:

```
List<object> foo = products.ToList<object>();
```

Or even just:

```
List<object> foo = new List<object>(products);
```

You can't pass the *existing list* because a `List<Product>` simply *isn't* a `List<object>`.

Of course if you could change your method to accept an `IEnumerable<object>` instead, that would work fine due to covariance. That may be feasible if you're only trying to *read* from the parameter collection.

Mind you, it's not clear why you need to then use reflection to create a `List<dynamic>` - what's your method actually doing? Why can't you just use:

```
List<dynamic> foo = new List<dynamic>(products);
```

Comment: And if the asker uses .NET 4.5, there's another **covariant** interface, [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx), and stuff like `List<T>` and `T[]` implements it, and because of the covariance an `IReadOnlyList<Product>` is also an `IReadOnlyList<object>` or `IReadOnlyList<dynamic>` without copying the collection (it's just a reference conversion). All of this assumes the type `Product` is a **class** because covariance won't work with value-types (struct, enum).